# Convert string to lowercase for property binding within xhtml?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

How could I always convert the property `username` to lower case?

This does not work:

```
<h:inputText value="#{userService.user.username.toLowerCase()}" />
```

as target gets "unreachable" by this.
How could I else do this?

Comment: how bout changing its getter `return username.toLowerCase();` (do some null check too)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```html
<h:inputText value="#{userService.user.username.toLowerCase()}" />
```

You can't perform a "set" operation on the given EL expression, while this is mandatory in order to update the model value with the submitted value. The `toLowerCase()` method expression doesn't have a corresponding setter method.

Technically, you should be creating a [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) for the job. Here's a kickoff example:

```
@FacesConverter("toLowerCaseConverter")
public class ToLowerCaseConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) {
        if (!(modelValue instanceof String)) { 
            return null; // Or throw ConverterException.
        }

        return ((String) modelValue).toLowerCase();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
        if (submittedValue == null) { 
            return null;
        }

        return submittedValue.toLowerCase();
    }

}
```

Use it as follows:

```html
<h:inputText value="#{userService.user.username}" converter="toLowerCaseConverter" />
```

You should preferably not clutter the model with conversion strategies.

Comment: Which converter is extended here? `import org.apache.myfaces.config.element.Converter;` would not work here as it would require a lot of override methods like `getConverterClass` `getConverterId` `getForClass`

Comment: Just the standard JSF converter. Have you never created one? It's the [`javax.faces.convert.Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html).

Comment: Ok we have to use *implements* here instead extends. Then it works, additionaly changing the *void* to String or Object.

Comment: Oops, sorry for that. Didn't had enough coffee at 05:00 am. Answer is been fixed. I should have used an IDE instead of the SO message editor.

Comment: no problem, anyway this is probably the best solution for lower case. It worked of course with the conversation within the setter, but as you said cluttering the model should be avoided.

Comment: One more suggestion to have a complete example here: `if (!(value instanceof String)) { return ""; }` as we cannot return an object if method is a String.

Comment: @ᴠɪɴᴄᴇɴᴛ: I usually don't add imports unless there's ambiguity. Just let IDE autocomplete imports and verify if it compiles. Moreover, the `Converter` link in my answers points to the javadoc.

Comment: @ᴠɪɴᴄᴇɴᴛ: missed that due to the double comment, I only saw last one.

Answer (score 4):

You can use jstl function for this

include: <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

and use  < h:inputText value="${fn:toLowerCase(string)}"/>

Or you can make username in lowercase in java by .toLowerCase().

Comment: Wrong. You cannot perform a "set" operation on a function expression.

Answer (score 1):

This way should work. As soon as you set the name, the name is lowecased.

```
String name;

public void setName(String name){
 this.name = name.toLowerCase();
}
```